# shoot on keypress in 2D game with XNA game studio

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm developing a 2D game with XNA game studio 4.0 and I need to make my "Hero" sprite shoot a shot sprite, which is a rectangle.

When I press left control to shoot, the shot is starting from my player. So far, it's ok, but the problem is that it never stops - its position never goes to `theVoid`.

Here is my code for shooting:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftControl) && isShotted == false)
    {
        isShotted = true;
        shotPosition = playerPosition;            
    }
    if (isShotted == true && (shotPosition.X <= shotPosition.X+150) )
    {
        shotPosition.X += shotSpeed.X * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }
    else 
    { 
        isShotted = false;
        shotPosition = theVoid;
    }
}
```

Some clarification:

- `playerPosition` is my "Hero" sprite position.
- `theVoid` is `Vector2 (700,700)`, when I set `shotPosition = theVoid` the shot dissapears.

Comment: `shotPosition.X <= shotPosition.X + 150` is always going to be true... I think you might have meant `playerPosition + 150`?

Answer (score 4):

The shot never disapears because you are updating `shotPosition.x` every update. You are checking:

```
if (isShotted == true && (shotPosition.X <= shotPosition.X+150) )
```

And then inside that `if` you increment `shotPosition.X`:

```
shotPosition.X += shotSpeed.X * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

One option to fix this would be to check `shotPosition.X` against the player position - per @jonhopkins comment.  If the player can move near the same speed as the shot though, they could just follow it and then the shot would never disappear, this may or may not be what you want.

Your other option is to store the position of where the shot was fired, and compare something like:

```
if (isShotted == true && (shotPosition.initialX+150 >= shotPosition.currentX) )
```

Make sure you think about this in terms of how your players and objects move around the coordinate system though. If your player is always stationary in regards to the x-axis that could simplify things compared to if they can run around the screen..

Comment: well in 
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftControl) && isShotted == false)
    {
        isShotted = true;
        shotPosition = playerPosition;            
    }
the position of shot is playerPosition so this is where the shot starts. and then i compare the position where i have fired the bullet and where it goes so your script is exactly like mine or maybe im wrong again.

Comment: and im not updating shotPosition i update it only if i press Left-Ctrl and if isShotted = false

Comment: ahh i got it ... shotPosition.X <= shotPosition.X+150 is always true

Comment: thanks guys really i made it. Really good site for my 2d game development very quick and right answers

Comment: @BorisTheBlade Glad you got it working! You're totally right about StackOverflow as well, it is a great resource for most any kind of development.  I'd recommend reading the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to get a feel for how things work here.